# Append data to text area

Tags: javascript

I have a few checkboxes that when clicked output to a textarea. This bit is working, however after each result gets listed there is a comma I don't know how to remove. Also I'd like to preload the textarea with some text and have the results listed below it without overwriting my preloaded text. So far I have this

```js
function updateTextArea() {
  var allVals = [];
  $('.taglist :checked').each(function(i) {

    allVals.push((i != 0 ? "\r\n" : "") + $(this).val());
  });
  $('#form1').val(allVals).attr('rows', allVals.length);

}
$(function() {
  $('.taglist input').click(updateTextArea);
  updateTextArea();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="textfield" id="form1" name="form1">My text here</textarea>
<div class="taglist">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 1">Value 1</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 2">Value 2</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 3">Value 3</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 4">Value 4</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 5">Value 5</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set an array as the argument of `val()`, it is implicitly converted to a comma separated string. You can either join the array using `allVals.join()`, or, if you don't need the values in array form at all, you can concatenate them as a string directly.

I also implemented your request to be able to keep the initial value in the following snippet, by saving it with `data()`. (You'll probably want to skip the check for omitting the first line break --edit: I implemented a dynamic check to see whether the initial textarea value is empty)

```js
function updateTextArea() {
  var allVals = $('#form1').data('initialVal'),
      lineCount = 1;
  $('.taglist :checked').each(function(i) {
    allVals+= (i != 0 || allVals.length > 0 ? "\r\n" : "") + $(this).val();
    lineCount++;
  });
  $('#form1').val(allVals).attr('rows', lineCount);

}
$(function() {
  $('.taglist input').click(updateTextArea);
  
  $('#form1').data('initialVal', $('#form1').val());
  updateTextArea();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="textfield" id="form1" name="form1">My text here</textarea>
<div class="taglist">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 1">Value 1</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 2">Value 2</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 3">Value 3</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 4">Value 4</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 5">Value 5</label>
</div>
```

Comment: @ Connum That's perfect! Thank you very much to all that helped.

Comment: @Connum Your snippet is not working, open snippet and check `Value 1`, it simply removes the line break but does not add `Value 1` to the text area. uncheck `Value 1` and check `Value 2` same problem. - If checking `Value 1` first after opening the snippet and then checking `Value 2` it shows `Value 1` but not `Value 2` someting wrong with your lines count most likely as it seems to add the values not doesn't resize the textarea correctly.

Comment: It's working perfectly for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Connum I'm using Chrome - I updated my previous comment, seems textarea re-sizing is screwed in chrome.

Comment: it's just a visual problem in some browsers... Firefox displays it correctly, some others, including Chrome, seem to handle the `rows` attribute and height calculation differently. But if you resize the textarea after change, you will see that the content is actually correct. Let me see if I can add some CSS or calculation to fix this, or feel free to edit my answer if you come up with something. It's not an actualy problem of the code, but sure the snippet should look fine in all browsers, that's right.

Comment: the resizing was in the original code: `$('#form1').val(allVals).attr('rows', allVals.length);` but as I see now, it was based on `.length`, which is 1-based, not 0-based, so I just adapted it to start with `1` in my snippet instead. All fine now. :)

Comment: @Connum I +1ed either way, just thought it was strange it cut of the bottom :)

Answer (score 2):

**Why you have commas?**

Because you **implicitly** call an `toString()` on your array, which will return your array items separated by comma. Join your array's items by empty string `''` and you will get normal text.

**Why you don't get the text ?**

You have set the text there, but in the jQuery `initializer` function you call `updateTextArea()` at the last line, so it will set `text` of your `textarea` with the `allVals`, which is empty at first time, when you don't select any value.

Here it calls `toString` implicitly on the `arr` and gets the string representation of your array.

```js
var arr = ['1', '2', '3'] ;

console.log(arr);
```

**Working Example**

```js
function updateTextArea() {
  var allVals = ['My text here'];
  $('.taglist :checked').each(function(i) {
    allVals.push((i != 0 ? "\r\n" : "") + $(this).val());
  });
  $('#form1').val(allVals.join('')).attr('rows', allVals.length);

}
$(function() {
  $('.taglist input').click(updateTextArea);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="textfield" id="form1" name="form1">My text here</textarea>
<div class="taglist">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 1">Value 1</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 2">Value 2</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 3">Value 3</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 4">Value 4</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 5">Value 5</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> After each result gets listed there is a comma I don't know how to
>   remove
>
> I'd like to preload the textarea with some text and have the results
>   listed below it without overwriting my preloaded text

You can get rid of the comma using `array.join('')`.
In regards to not overwriting existing text, you could store the existing text and re-use it when writing the array to the text area

```js
// if you want just the original text and no new line after it do:
var originalText =  $('#form1').val();

 // if you want a new line after the original text do:
 originalText =  $('#form1').val() + '\r\n';

function updateTextArea() {
  var allVals = [];
  allVals.push(originalText);
  
  $('.taglist :checked').each(function(i) {
    allVals.push((i != 0 ? "\r\n" : "") + $(this).val());
  });
  
  $('#form1').val(allVals.join('')).attr('rows', allVals.length);

}

$(function() {
  $('.taglist input').click(updateTextArea);
  updateTextArea();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="textfield" id="form1" name="form1">My text here</textarea>
<div class="taglist">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 1">Value 1</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 2">Value 2</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 3">Value 3</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 4">Value 4</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 5">Value 5</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. New to javascript. Any idea how to preload text though?

Comment: @Greg If you want the text you originally specified to stay you could add it to the array before writing it to the `textarea`, I added an example for that.

Answer (score 0):

Like this it will work, look at **join**

```js
        function updateTextArea() {     
           var allVals = [];
           $('.taglist :checked').each(function(i) {
                  
               allVals.push((i!=0?"\r\n":"")+ $(this).val());
           });
           $('#form1').val(allVals.join(" ")).attr('rows',allVals.length) ;
            
           }
           $(function() {
              $('.taglist input').click(updateTextArea);
              updateTextArea();
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="textfield" id="form1" name="form1">My text here</textarea>
        <div class="taglist">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 1">Value 1</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 2">Value 2</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 3">Value 3</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 4">Value 4</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 5">Value 5</label>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

http://codepen.io/joaocarvalhowd-1472219370/pen/egoBKQ?editors=1111]

```
    var text_initial = document.querySelector('#form1').value  + "\r\n";

function checkboxsListen() {
  var checks = document.querySelectorAll('.taglist input[type="checkbox"]');

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(checks, function(check) {

    check.addEventListener('change', function() {
      updateTextArea();
    })

  })
}

checkboxsListen();

function updateTextArea() {
  var textarea = document.querySelector('#form1')
  textarea.value = text_initial;
  var checks_selected = document.querySelectorAll('.taglist input[type="checkbox"]:checked');

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(checks_selected, function(check) {
    textarea.value += check.value + "\r\n";
  })
}
```