# How can I concatenate values of checkbox and textarea?

Tags: checkbox, text, concatenation

I want to concatenate value of checkbox and textarea with the simplest approach possible (hopefully one javascript code).

I will have about 400 checkboxes to choose from. After each 20 check boxes, there will be one textarea to comment on the reason checkboxes were selected.

These selections will result in a paragraph that I can copy past to a document and edit

For example, I can check the box for "blue car" "better than" "red car" and in area type "because I like red color. "Kelly Corn" "divorced" "John James" and in area type"because he was nasty" and in the text area name="past_info_here"; I will have

> blue car is better than red car because I like red color. Kelly Corn divorced John James because he was nasty"

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

</head>

<body>

  <textarea name="past_info_here" cols="100" class="textfield" id="final_pragraph"></textarea>

</p>
<br>
<b>OPTION 1</b>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value=" Red car "> red car</label>
<input type="checkbox" value=" blue car "> red car</label>
<input type="checkbox" value=" is better than "> better than</label>
<input type="checkbox" value=" Red car "> red car</label>
<input type="checkbox" value=" blue car "> red car</label>
<br> because<BR>
<input type="textarea" > reason</label>

<br>
<b>OPTION 2</b>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value=" John James "> John </label>
<input type="checkbox" value=" Kelly Corn "> kelly</label>
<input type="checkbox" value=" married "> married</label>
<input type="checkbox" value=" divorced"> divorced</label>
<input type="checkbox" value=" John James "> John </label>
<input type="checkbox" value=" Kelly Corn "> kelly</label>
<br> because<BR>
<input type="textarea" > reason</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try setting the same class to all checkbox and textarea,  then document.getElementsByClassName() ... and you'll get a collection with the info you wanted.. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

Comment: Would it be potto show me in simple example? Please?

Comment: sorry I meant would it be possible to show me in a simple example? for example, in the above code, could you please insert a function? I would greatly appreciate that. sorry for the typo above, the autocorrect function of iphone!

Comment: You already have an example in the link. Try it.  If necessary, update your question with your new code

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply,
I found the following which is what i want with one difference that I want to combine values of check boxes as well as free text from text area
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273075/append-data-to-text-area
any suggestions? I need the simplest function since I will have a large number of check boxes and text areas. I need to make different combinations from pre-typed text to create new "customized" paragraphs (not really customized since I will have already most of the text in the values of checkboxes).